# Golang AWS S3manager multipartreader w/ Goroutines

Tags: go, amazon-s3, goroutine

I'm creating an endpoint that allows a user to upload several files at the same time and store them in S3. Currently I'm able to achieve this using MultipartReader and s3manager but only in a non-synchronous fashion.

I'm trying to implement Go routines to speed this functionality up and have multiple files uploaded to S3 concurrently, but a data race error is causing trouble. I think *s3manager might not be goroutine safe as the docs say it is.
(Code works synchronously if go-statement is replaced with function code).

Could implementing mutex locks possibly fix my error?

```
func uploadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    counter := 0
    switch r.Method {
    // GET to display the upload form.
    case "GET":
        err := templates.Execute(w, nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
        }
        // POST uploads each file and sends them to S3
    case "POST":
        c := make(chan string)
        // grab the request.MultipartReader
        reader, err := r.MultipartReader()
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        // copy each part to destination.
        for {
            part, err := reader.NextPart()
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            // if part.FileName() is empty, skip this iteration.
            if part.FileName() == "" {
                continue
            }
            counter++
            go S3Upload(c, part)
        }
        for i := 0; i < counter; i++ {
          fmt.Println(<-c)
         }
        // displaying a success message.
        err = templates.Execute(w, "Upload successful.")
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
        }
    default:
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
    }
}  

func S3Upload(c chan string, part *multipart.Part) {
    bucket := os.Getenv("BUCKET")
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String(os.Getenv("REGION"))},
    )
    if err != nil {
        c <- "error occured creating session"
        return
    }
    uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)
    _, err = uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(part.FileName()),
        Body:   part,
    })
    if err != nil {
        c <- "Error occurred attempting to upload to S3"
        return
    }
    // successful upload
    c <- "successful upload"
}
```

Comment: Your question reminded me of this article.
http://marcio.io/2015/07/handling-1-million-requests-per-minute-with-golang/
The authors had to figure out a way to upload to s3 at scale. Might be a worthwhile read for you.

Comment: Also, you may not want to create a new s3 session with every POST, that won't scale well. You can create a single instance of a session and a single instance of an s3manager that you then can use for the life cycle of your server. It will reduce object/memory churn, reduce GC, and therefore your program will be faster.

Comment: To avoid race conditions, you may want to consider using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/#Uploader.UploadWithIterator. It is safe to use Upload concurrently to upload WHOLE files. It breaks those files into parts for you. You aren't sending in whole files but parts of the same file. How do you expect it to maintain order? Hence the race condition. If you want to use Upload read the whole file and send that off to AWS.

Comment: Lastly, if you do use upload, UploadInput's Body is a io.Reader, you can pass the body of the Request directly into upload, let it handle consuming the body in parts and defer close the Body to ensure you release your memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

^ see all the comments above,

here is some modified code example, channels not useful here.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "sync"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
)

var (
    setupUploaderOnce sync.Once
    uploader          *s3manager.Uploader
    bucket            string
    region            string
)
// ensure sessions and uploader are setup only once using a Singleton pattern
func setupUploader() {
    setupUploaderOnce.Do(func() {
        bucket = os.Getenv("BUCKET")
        region = os.Getenv("REGION")
        sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String(region)})
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)
    })
}

// normally singleton stuff is packaged out and called before starting the server, but to keep the example a single file, load it up here
func init() {
    setupUploader()
}

func uploadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    counter := 0
    switch r.Method {
    // GET to display the upload form.
    case "GET":
        err := templates.Execute(w, nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
        }
        // POST uploads each file and sends them to S3
    case "POST":
        var buf bytes.Buffer
        // "file" is defined by the form field, change it to whatever your form sets it too
        file, header, err := r.FormFile("file")
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        // close the file
        defer file.Close()
        fileName := strings.Split(header.Filename, ".")
        // load the entire file data to the buffer
        _, err = io.Copy(&buf, file)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        // copy each part to destination.
        go S3Upload(buf, fileName[0])
        // displaying a success message.
        err = templates.Execute(w, "Upload successful.")
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
        }
    default:
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
    }
}

// keeping this simple, do something with the err, like log
// if the uploader fails in the goroutine, there is potential
// for false positive uploads... channels are not really good here
// either, for that, bubble the error up,
// and don't spin up a goroutine.. same thing as waiting for the channel to return.
func S3Upload(body bytes.Buffer, fileName string) {
    _, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(fileName),
        Body:   bytes.NewReader(body.Bytes()),
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the useful tips! The example you gave is perfect for a single file upload so I made a few edits myself to make applicable for multiple files at the same time.